# css selecionar apenas primeiro nível

Tags: html, css, css-seletores

Tenho um menu com até 3 níveis de listas aninhadas. Preciso selecionar apenas o texto do primeiro nível e ignorar o conteúdo aninhado. Tentei usar `.menu > ul> li {}` (e algumas variações disto) e não resultou no que precisava.

Tentei usar `.menu li:first-child > ul` e resultou no oposto do que eu preciso, ou seja, trouxe tudo menos o primeiro nível. Tentei usar o `pseudo-seletor :not` na condição acima, mas não consegui.

Então preciso de ajuda com este seletor. Como fazer?

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
  <li>Item nível 1
     <ul>
        <li>Item nível 2
            <ul>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item nível 1
     <ul>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Consegue por o seu código feito até agora no CODEPEN ou JSFIDDLE? 
Ficará mais fácil de enteder o que você gostaria de fazer. ( Eu estou confuso ).

Comment: O primeiro exemplo devia ter funcionado, a não ser que seu HTML não esteja na estrutura que estou pensando. Seria melhor se você colocasse um exemplo, assim como o amigo acima disse.

Comment: @ThiagoYoith coloquei o html para deixar claro como está a estrutura. Na realidade o objetivo final é pegar os textos que no exemplo são "Item nível 1" e ignorar o restante, usando jquery. Mas o gargalo está nesse seletor que não estou acertando. Obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeD, poste exatamente seu código, aqui ou no JsFiddle, CodePen... Por favor.

Comment: @Gumball o código é este do tópico, não tem mais. São listas aninhadas. Como selecionar apenas o texto do 1º nível. No exemplo, como selecionar os textos "Item nível 1". Grato.

Comment: Por que não apenas colocar uma classe específica pra esses caras?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu entendi o que você deseja:

```css
ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

ul li ul li > ul{
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover > ul > li:hover > ul{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
  <li>Item nível 1
     <ul>
        <li>Item nível 2
            <ul>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item nível 1
     <ul>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1):

Depois de procurar bastante, a melhor alternativa que encontrei foi essa:

```
$('.menu > ul > li').clone().children().remove().end()
```

Veja o exemplo no meu [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/leandrosimoes/0c5x7ffo/5/)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Show! Era exatamente isto!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou, abraz! Quando puder, da um upvote aí na resposta. Valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Os estilos no CSS propagam para os elementos contidos em um elemento onde o estilo foi definido. Isto é, os estilos para um elemento do primeiro nível de uma lista serão aplicados também nos elementos dos próximos níveis. Uma solução pode ser "desfazer" a aplicação do estilo. No CSS 3 existe a propriedade [`initial`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp) que pode ajudar.

```css
.menu li {
    color: red;
}

.menu li li {
    color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<ul>
  <li>Item nível 1
     <ul>
        <li>Item nível 2
            <ul>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
                <li>Item nível 3</li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item nível 1
     <ul>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
        <li>Item nível 2</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Simples e objetivo. :)